# Facebook Graph API call Limit for public pages share count

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch share count using graph api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=";
"SELECT url, total_count,share_count FROM link_stat WHERE url in (";
```

`private void callFB(List validUrlList,Map> dataMap,long timeStamp,Double calibrationFactor){
        try {
            StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("List Size " + validUrlList.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < (validUrlList.size() - 1); i++) {
                urlString.append("\"" + validUrlList.get(i) + "\",");
            }
            urlString.append("\""
                    + validUrlList.get(validUrlList.size() - 1) + "\"");
            String out = getConnection(fbURL+URLEncoder.encode(
                    queryPrefix
                            + urlString.toString() + ")", "utf-8"));
            dataMap = getSocialPopularity(validUrlList.toArray(), dataMap);
            getJSON(out, dataMap, timeStamp,calibrationFactor);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`


This API does not require any access token as I am trying to fetch *public URLs*.
I run batch request where each batch contains 100 url total batches are 20. It is run on a server.

This API was running well for whole one year but now it is always showing me issue that API limit exceeded.

I run it from my local laptop it works fine but when I run it from same server it gives me error.

Could you please help me how it suddenly crossed limit as call size is same for last one year.

Regards
Virendra Agarwal

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't use long-deprecated endpoints, as they can stop working anytime...

Comment: @Tobi i did not get long deprecated end point. Could you please explain it more.

Comment: FQL is deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_1 *The FQL and REST APIs are no longer available in v2.1*

Comment: @Tobi Could you please suggest us which one we should follow now. As it does not require any access token so we were using it

Comment: HI @Tobi i tried two versions  http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://blog.sriraman.in/ it does not ask for access token second http://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/?id=http://blog.sriraman.in/ it ask for access token could you please suggest more on this which version we should use.

Comment: Either way, it will also be subject to rate limiting.

Comment: Thanks @Tobi i am using without access token part currently I will also explre access token options along with it.

Comment: HI @Tobi i went through access token definitions. Token will be created by authentication from client side. BUt if i am looking to read likes and shares for public pages (Articles news stories) from server side code there be now client authentication. So how i will create a access token for long live session and how to extend it. This is my confusion here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **rate limit** provided for every client from where you call the API, you might have exceeded the same.

There must be *rate limit timeout*  given. Wait for that time and try again, this is not a kind of problem, but it helps in maintaining the server loads coming from different clients.

Comment: I checked there was not timeout given thats the issue. It gives me this error  java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+url%2C+total_count%2Cshare_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url+in+%28%22http%3A%2F%

Comment: Can you post the JSON you get in return of the request

Comment: Sure give me 5 minutes.

Comment: Vivek Singh i tried to fetch out put it again gave me error 403 no json in out put. I added Java code which data from Facebook. When i make connection i give me error 403.

Comment: try this [link](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-Facebook-Open-Graph-API-rate-limit). It has all the information related to your question.

Comment: Let me know if the link given above works for you or you still have issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96946/discussion-between-viren-and-vivek-singh).